# A Weird Pagination Problem with memoir, amsref

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, chapters, amsrefs

I have a weird problem to describe. Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,oldfontcommands,12pt]{memoir}
% \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,oldfontcommands,12pt]{memoir}
%%% A Hack to use amsrefs
\let\bibsection\relax

%%% INCLUDE THE PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd,amsrefs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx,soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.0588,.0941,.333}
\setsecheadstyle{\color{nicered}\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

%%%FORMATING FOR CHAPTER
\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{daleif1}
%===================================================
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily}

\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{2pt}
\makefootrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{2pt}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead {myruled}{}{\small\sffamily\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead {myruled}{}{\small\sffamily\rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot {myruled}{\small\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot {myruled}{}{}{\small\thepage}
\makeatletter % because of \@chapapp
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
  \nouppercaseheads\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{
  \@chapapp\ }{.\ }
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createplainmark {toc}{both} {\contentsname}
  \createplainmark {lof}{both} {\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark {lot}{both} {\listtablename}
  \createplainmark {bib}{both} {\bibname}
  \createplainmark {index}{both} {\indexname}
  \createplainmark {glossary}{both} {\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\linespread{1.5}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}

%==================================================================================================================

\newcommand{\mar}[1]{\marginpar{\small \it #1}}
\marginparwidth 1 in

\newcounter{cnt1}
\newcounter{cnt2}
\newcommand{\blr}{\begin{list}{$($\roman{cnt1}$)$}
 {\usecounter{cnt1} \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}
\newcommand{\bla}{\begin{list}{$(\alph{cnt2})$}
 {\usecounter{cnt2} \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}
\newcommand{\el}{\end{list}}


\renewcommand{\biblistfont}{%
  \normalfont
  \normalsize
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{cover(mem)}
\cleardoublepage
\include{title(mem)}
\cleardoublepage
\include{dedication(mem)}
\cleardoublepage
% \include{acknowledgement}
% \cleardoublepage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{myruled}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-11]
% \createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
% \pagenumbering{gobble}
 \chapter*[Bibliography]{}
\begin{bibdiv}
% \pdfbookmark{\bibname}{Bibliography}{}
% \pagenumbering{arabic}
% \setcounter{page}{93}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{Darwin}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin1}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin2}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin3}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin4}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin5}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin6}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin7}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin8}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin9}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin10}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin11}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin12}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin13}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin14}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin15}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

I realise that this is perhaps not the right way to do it. The problem is

(1) In the code, there is a new chapter (`\chapter*`) which clears a double page.

(2) Suppose on the contrary, if I get rid of that, I get into trouble in the header and footer.

And, the bookmark for Bibliography is not being created. I solved the problem by using `[openany]` option and using `\cleartorecto` as the need may be at the end of chapters (and this solution is manual and does not work if the last non-empty page before Bibliography is an even-numbered page); see the commented out bits of code.

I'd be glad if someone can point me to the right way of doing it.

Comment: not being a user of `memoir`, this is just a guess.  `amsrefs` provides an environment `bibchapter` that may be useful, rather than having an explicit call for `\chapter*{Bibliography}`.  not related to this problem, but just a matter of general housekeeping, you're calling for `graphicx` twice among your `\usepackage` entries, and if i remember correctly, `epsfig` is either redundant or obsolete.

Comment: now is the time to confess: the code is not mine. I am trying to help someone, although I created the MWE. Anyway, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton OK! The double page issue disappears! However, the other issues (viz bookmark, header issues) remain. I'd be glad if you could help me with that too!

Comment: as i said, i'm not a `memoir` user, so i'm not sure how a lot of things work.  i'd have to do quite a bit of research to figure out how headers work, and i suspect others already know how to deal with that.  regarding bookmarks, look for documentation on using `\pdfbookmark`; i think that's what might be involved here.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the same pagination error with a simple MWE trimming the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, as **barbara beeton** suggested, use the `bibchapter` environment instead of `bibdiv`; to recover the proper heading, you can redefine `bibchapter` to use `\bibmark`, as in

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{bibchapter}[1][\bibname]{%
    \begingroup
        \protected@edef\@{%
                \endgroup
            \protect\chapter*{#1}%
            \protect\bib@div@mark{#1}%
        }%
        \@\bibmark
}{\par}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,oldfontcommands,12pt]{memoir}
% \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,oldfontcommands,12pt]{memoir}
%%% A Hack to use amsrefs
\let\bibsection\relax

%%% INCLUDE THE PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd,amsrefs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx,soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.0588,.0941,.333}
\setsecheadstyle{\color{nicered}\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

%%%FORMATING FOR CHAPTER
\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{nicered}}
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{daleif1}
%===================================================
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily}

\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{2pt}
\makefootrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{2pt}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead {myruled}{}{\small\sffamily\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead {myruled}{}{\small\sffamily\rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot {myruled}{\small\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot {myruled}{}{}{\small\thepage}
\makeatletter % because of \@chapapp
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
  \nouppercaseheads\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{
  \@chapapp\ }{.\ }
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createplainmark {toc}{both} {\contentsname}
  \createplainmark {lof}{both} {\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark {lot}{both} {\listtablename}
  \createplainmark {bib}{both} {\bibname}
  \createplainmark {index}{both} {\indexname}
  \createplainmark {glossary}{both} {\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\linespread{1.5}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}

%==================================================================================================================

\newcommand{\mar}[1]{\marginpar{\small \it #1}}
\marginparwidth 1 in

\newcounter{cnt1}
\newcounter{cnt2}
\newcommand{\blr}{\begin{list}{$($\roman{cnt1}$)$}
 {\usecounter{cnt1} \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}
\newcommand{\bla}{\begin{list}{$(\alph{cnt2})$}
 {\usecounter{cnt2} \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}
\newcommand{\el}{\end{list}}


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{bibchapter}[1][\bibname]{%
    \begingroup
        \protected@edef\@{%
                \endgroup
            \protect\chapter*{#1}%
            \protect\bib@div@mark{#1}%
        }%
        \@\bibmark
}{\par}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\biblistfont}{%
  \normalfont
  \normalsize
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{cover(mem)}
\cleardoublepage
\include{title(mem)}
\cleardoublepage
\include{dedication(mem)}
\cleardoublepage
% \include{acknowledgement}
% \cleardoublepage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{myruled}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-11]
% \pagenumbering{gobble}
%\chapter*[Bibliography]{}
\begin{bibchapter}
%\begin{bibdiv}
% \pdfbookmark{\bibname}{Bibliography}{}
% \pagenumbering{arabic}
% \setcounter{page}{93}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{Darwin}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin1}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin2}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin3}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin4}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin5}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin6}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin7}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin8}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin9}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin10}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin11}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin12}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin13}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin14}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }
 \bib{Darwin15}{article}{
       author={Darwin, Charles.},   
       title={Elephants, A New Perspective},
        date={1972},
        ISSN={1234},
     journal={Nature},
      volume={90},
       pages={90\ndash 128},
 }

\end{biblist}
%\end{bibdiv}
\end{bibchapter}
\end{document}
```

An image of the bibliography and the previous pages:

[image]